# Unserialize data and check it against an id in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have a row of IDs in a database that has been serialized.

What I'm trying to do is check those serialized IDs against a known ID to see if it should be excluded or not.

for example:

`"SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE id = 4 AND checkID != 'an id in the serialized column' "`

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saying what form the IDs are in, but the basic way is using `IN`:

```
AND checkid NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

Comment: @kylex well, the basic logic is the same. If they're in array form, implode them into a comma separated list, and do a NOT IN on them.

Comment: @Pekka is there any chance you could post a sample of your NOT IN clause im currently learning it and found it interesting but i dont see how it would read against a serialized field, or perhaps i got it wrong and the checkid would need to actually be a string or int field instead of a serialized one. pardon me with such a question. Was checking out php manual but i am still unsure about it.

Comment: @Prix what kind of data are you using? An Array? Please show a live example.

Comment: So I must be missing something:
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE id = '1' AND 2010-6-7 NOT IN (2010-6-21,2010-6-7)

is not working Any suggestions?

Comment: @kylex how about adding quotes? :) `"2010-6-21", "2010-6-7-"...`